# How to transform a datapoint for a prediction in sklearn

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have built a model in `sklearn`, which I have saved in a pickle form. However, in order to get the best results I could get, I had to remove features, create another ones, use one-hot encoding, e.t.c.

Now, I am given a new datapoint in the initial form and I need to make a prediction. Is there any easy way to transform the datapoint, such that my built model can make a prediction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the same transformations to test set as you did to train set. One of the ways to do it is to write a function to process data and use it. So you will have something like this:

```
def process_data(x):
    # process data, remove features and so on

     return processed_data

X_train_processed = process(X_train)
X_test_processed = process(X_test)
```